# How does Mathematica Find Integer Roots For Certain Transcendental Functions?

Tags: equation-solving

I have these two equations: $$f(x)=(\cos(\frac{n}{x} \pi)\cos(x\pi))-1$$ and $$g(x)=\sin^2(\frac{n}{x}\pi)+\sin^2(x \pi)$$ where $n$ can be any integer. These two functions are what mathematicians call "transcendental equations", ie. their roots can not be found through analytic means, but usually through numerical methods. These methods usually give approximations, but when I solve them with Mathematica, they found the exact integer roots. So, I'm asking how did they do this? What method did they employ?

Comment: I doubt its possible to know exactly. But notice the simple case: Solve[Cos[x Pi] == 1, x] is solved easily. One might guess that more complex versions (such as your f(x) and g(x) build on this kind of simple (and likely "built in") answer.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe they check where $n/x$ is an integer and see whether $n$ is an integer as well?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward to guess the solutions to each using some logical arguments - not strictly symbol manipulation. I'm not sure how much of that MMA can do though. Maybe it finds numerical solutions and has some provision to test integers if the numerical solution is converging to the integer within some precision? Some of the folks here have a pretty deep knowledge of how these things work, maybe one of them will chime in.

Comment: @N.J.Evans Maybe, I  know the roots to $f(x)$ are maxima and for $g(x)$ it's  minima-- so maybe they calculate the deriative, find all the zeroes in the range (somehow), then check all of them. However, I do't think that's true as for big $n$, there are a lot of extrema very close together.

Comment: @N.J.Evans You said something about "guessing the solutions" using "some logical arguments". What do you mean by that?

Comment: @QuoteDave For f(x), Cos has a range [-1,1], so Cos(a)*Cos(b) = 1 iff |Cos(a)|=|Cos(b)|=1 and the signs are the same. Since Cos(a)=+/-1 iff a = j*Pi where j is an integer whose parity determines the sign, both x and n/x must be integers of the same parity.

Comment: @N.J.Evans Well, that only divides any given range (where only one root must lie in) by around 50% if you know that one x is odd. That still doesn't answer how can they do it.

Comment: @QuoteDave Can you provide the actual code you used to find the roots?

Comment: Neither Reduce[Cos[n*Pi/x]*Cos[x*Pi] == 1, x, Reals] nor Reduce[Cos[5*Pi/x]*Cos[x*Pi] == 1, x, Reals] do the job in version 12.0. Could you support your claim by  a working code? The FindInstance[Cos[5*Pi/x]*Cos[x*Pi] == 1, x, Reals, 2] command fails too.

Comment: Your equations are also algebraic for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, methods of solving polynomial equations apply. I believe this is how MA does it.

Comment: @yarchik Then how would you solve these types of polynomial equations?